# How to return this , self type from extension function in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have implemented successfully some extension in typescript that works, but I would like to return this type instead of void.

```
interface Array<T> {
  pushAll(other: T[]): void

  randomize(): void
}

Array.prototype.pushAll = function <T>(other: T[]): void {
  this.push(...other)
}

Array.prototype.randomize = function (): void {
  this.sort(() => Math.random() * 2 - 1)
}
```

But when I try it it gives compile errors:

```
interface Array<T> {
  pushAll(other: T[]): this

  randomize(): this
}

Array.prototype.pushAll = function <T>(other: T[]): this {
  this.push(...other)
  return this
}

Array.prototype.randomize = function (): this {
  this.sort(() => Math.random() * 2 - 1)
  return this
}
```

Error: This type is available only in non static....
Also suggestion `any[]` does not work. 
Also I tired to declare return type as `T[]` with no luck too.

I am coming to typescript from higher level languages like kotlin, swift, c#, objective-c where this is cleanly possible, so I can write functions that I can chain still have type safety.
Thanks.

(edit)
I found workaround just for this and some other similar case, returning `Array<T>` type. But I can define returning this in interfaces and implement it, just in prototypes function definition this wont work..

Comment: T is argument type I need to return self type , but I found workaround just for this case , returning Array<T> type. So that is ok for this case for now still looking for returning this for other cases. But I can define returning this in interfaces and implement it just in prototypes function definition this wont work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove the types entirely from your definition. Since typescript already knows the types from the interface declaration, they'll be applied to your definition via [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).

So, your example would look like this:

```
interface Array<T> {
  pushAll(other: T[]): this
  randomize(): this
}

Array.prototype.pushAll = function (other) {
  this.push(...other)
  return this
}

Array.prototype.randomize = function () {
  this.sort(() => Math.random() * 2 - 1)
  return this
}
```

Comment: Looks good but I should test it before accept it but maybe I will trust it as it seams quite clear now Thanks .. will be back to my typescript codebase soon so will definitely try it out !

Answer (score 0):

This is workaround, but not exactly what I am looking for.

```
interface Array<T> {
  pushAll(other: T[]): Array<T>

  randomize(): Array<T>
}

Array.prototype.pushAll = function <T>(other: T[]): Array<T> {
  this.push(...other)
  return this
}

Array.prototype.randomize = function <T>(): Array<T> {
  this.sort(() => Math.random() * 2 - 1)
  return this
}
```